# How to use ORDER BY GROUP BY & LIMIT

Tags: postgis

How do I use `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY` & `LIMIT` in the following query through column name `KPH`?

```
SELECT * 
FROM data 
WHERE  ST_Within(
    ST_Transform(geom, 2163), 
    ST_Buffer(
        ST_Transform(
            ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (77.2089421749115 28.5225030428734, 77.2088992595673 28.5223333626164,77.1612417697906 28.5640959203597)', 4326),
            2163),
        500)
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be, for example:

```
    SELECT kph, count(*) 
    FROM data 
    WHERE  ST_Within(
        ST_Transform(geom, 2163), 
        ST_Buffer(
            ST_Transform(
                ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (77.2089421749115 28.5225030428734, 77.2088992595673 28.5223333626164,77.1612417697906 28.5640959203597)', 4326),
                2163),
            500)
    GROUP BY kph
    ORDER BY count
    LIMIT 5
        );
```